# mysql php update with a variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

So I've been at this for a while now and anything I do or research turns up more errors. I keep getting this error: **Fatal error:** Call to a member function query() on a non-object with code that looks like this. the pic column is for a profile picture directory they uploaded.

```
$newTarget_file = "uploads/picture.png"

....

$sql = "UPDATE users SET pic='$newTarget_file' WHERE username=:username";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

also this is a php that is submited to that saves the picture they upload and the directory is the $newTarget_file . This is realy frustrating my on how I do this. Thanks in advance for the help.

Basically I want to update the pic column where username=:username with a variable I have already $newTarget_file . what do I do?

Comment: The connection object `$conn` is not in scope where you are calling this. Is this inside a function?  I note also that you are using PDO-style named parameters with `query()` which is incorrect. This should be [`prepare()/exeute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with `:username` as a parameter.

Comment: `=:` looks like you are binding a value, but I don't see a bind statement. also why is there  a `.` after `pic` in `pic=.$newTarget_file`

Comment: Please post the code where `$conn` is defined.

Comment: Ive been basicaly been following this link but want to put a variable in as an update http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, the error is because your connection object doesn't exist.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Based on the tutorial you are following, have you implemented this?

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbuser, $dbpw, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

You should have gotten a connection error before the query ever tried to run. Also, as Michael pointed out, you can't used named parameters with mysqli. It's only supported in PDO, but you can still use placeholders. Your new code should look something like this.

```
if (!($stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET pic=? WHERE username=?"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
    exit;
}
if (!$stmt->bind_param("ss", $newTarget_file, $username)) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    exit;
}
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    exit;
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: That doesn't give anymore errors but it doesn't do anything to my database

Comment: actualy it did. I forgot to redefine $username as the user thats logged in, not the user of the mysql database. Thank you SO MUCH!

Comment: You're welcome Jacob, I updated the answer to show more detailed error reporting. Please be sure to accept the answer if it resolved your issue.